# Exibir data atual em layout manipulado por ViewPager

Tags: android

Quando clico num botão da Main Activity cria-se um ViewPager que me possibilita transitar entre 7 layouts que possuo. O pager está setado para apresentar primeiramente o layout chamado "domingo.xml" e tudo funciona normalmente. Eu quero apenas que nesse layout seja mostrada uma data, para isso utilizo esse código:

```
    Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE - dd/MM", local);
    Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String mostrarData = sdf.format(d).toUpperCase(local);
    final TextView textoData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textoData.setText(mostrarData);
```

Criei um layout novo só para testar e o código da data funciona e exibe a data normalmente, mas no layout domingo.xml (que é manipulado pelo ViewPager) não consigo de jeito nenhum.

Esse é o código do botão que chama o ViewPager:

```
public void btTela1(View v) {
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Pager.class));
}
```

E este é o código do ViewPager:

```
public class Pager extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pager);

    AdapterPages adapter = new AdapterPages();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}}
```

Há ainda o código do PagerAdapter que serve para configurar o ViewPager. Onde devo escrever o código da data ? Já tentei em vários lugares, mas sempre dá erro. Não sei também se há algum erro conceitual que eu não entendo. Sou novo em programação e esta é a primeira vez que posto em um fórum. Se for necessário mais informações me falem que eu adiciono. Obrigado.

Código do PagerAdapter:

```
public class AdapterPages extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 7;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.domingo;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.segunda;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.terca;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.quarta;
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.quinta;
        break;
    case 5:
        resId = R.layout.sexta;
        break;
    case 6:
        resId = R.layout.sabado;
        break;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {

    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}}
```

Código do domingo.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_domingo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#BEBEBE"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    ...
```

A partir do que @Wakim me ensinou eu modifiquei uma pequena parte do código do PagerAdapter e ficou assim:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE - dd/MM", local);
Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String mostrarData = sdf.format(d).toUpperCase(local);
TextView textoData = (TextView) collection
        .findViewById(R.id.data_domingo);
textoData.setText(mostrarData);
return view;
```

Agora a data apareceu, porém, quando deslizo para o terceiro layout trava tudo. O que está acontecendo ?

Comment: Não basta atribuir a `String` (da data formatada) dentro do método `getView` do `AdapterPages`? Seria legal colocar apenas o código do `AdapterPages` e seu xml da `View` que ele cria e adiciona ao `ViewPager`.

Comment: @Wakim acrescentei os códigos que pediu...

Comment: Obrigado Felipe, poderia me dizer onde exatamente usa o código que altera o `textoData` em relação ao `ViewPager` ou foi só para testes?

Comment: @Wakim Usei para teste e também tentei escrever o código da data todo diretamente tanto no ViewPager quanto no PagerAdapter. Onde seria o correto ?

Comment: O mais correto é no `PagerAdapter`. Você precisa adicionar uma lógica dentro do `getView` que preencha o `TextView`. E você não precisa de um layout para cada dia (se o layout é parecido), basta um e adicionar logica para customizar dependendo da posição.

Comment: @Wakim São parecidos, eu entendo o que seria essa lógica, mas ainda não sei fazê-la. Você poderia me passar um exemplo de como deveria ficar esse getView ?

Comment: Sim, vou preparar uma resposta com essa idéia que eu sugeri.

Comment: @Wakim Ok, muito obrigado. E não repara não, comecei a pouco tempo.

Comment: Ok, entendi. Supondo que ainda está usando aquele switch, você não pode usar o R.id.data_domingo fixo, porque ele é somente do domingo.xml, no caso do segunda.xml o id é outro, certo? Para isso você vai ter que criar uma variável chamada textViewId e setar conforme o valor do switch (igual ao resId). E usar o findViewById(textViewId) no view e não no container.

Comment: Acho que entendi, vou tentar e já te respondo, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Wakim desculpa a demora, funcionou perfeitamente, o emulador de vez em qndo agarra, mas no aparelho tá perfeito. Adicionei um If pra cada caso, como esse: if (position == 1) {
TextView textoData = (TextView) collection
    .findViewById(R.id.data_segunda);   textoData.setText(mostrarData);
}
Acredito que não seja o correto, mas funcionou, muito obrigado pelo empenho em me ajudar. Não sei se tem regra, mas te add no face. Vlw, boa noite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `ViewPager` trabalha de forma parecida que o `ListView`, exibindo uma pequena parte do modelo associado.

O Modelo é associado através de um `Adapter`, onde o mesmo é responsável por retornar a presentação visual do modelo, para uma dada posição.

No caso o seu modelo é uma lista de datas, que pode ser derivado a partir de apenas uma data.

Vou assumir que o `domingo.xml` será o padrão para todas as datas, onde o que varia é o conteúdo do `TextView` cujo ID é `data_domingo` que ele exibe. Caso haja mais alterações no layout, é só falar que eu ajudo a montar.

Sua **`Activity Pager`** continua o mesmo.

O que muda é o seu `AdapterPages` que fica:

```
public class AdapterPages extends PagerAdapter {

    // Data base do ViewPager (posição 0), onde cada posição derivará dessa
    Calendar mBaseDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    // DateFormat usado para formatar a data
    DateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE - dd/MM", Locale.getDefault());

    // É legal "cachear" o LayoutInflater, para não ficar requisitando um toda hora. 
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public AdapterPages() {
        // Configurar a data base para corresponder ao primeiro dia da semana, domingo.
        mBaseDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
        mBaseDate.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mBaseDate.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        mBaseDate.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

        // get start of this week in milliseconds
        mBaseDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, mBaseDate.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Ok, sao 7 dias
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        if(mInflater == null) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(collection.getContext());
        }

        // Infla o layout padrão do ViewPager. É retornado uma
        // referência para a raiz (LinearLayout).
        // A partir dele, você consegue acessar todos os filhos.
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.domingo, null);

        TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.data_domingo);

        // Calculo qual o dia baseado na posicao e no dia base
        Calendar currentDate = (Calendar) mBaseDate.clone();
        currentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, posicao);

        // Fornece a data formatada relativa à posição do modelo
        tv.setText(mDateFormat.format(currentDate.getDate()).toUpperCase());

        // Voce pode fazer mais customizacoes aqui baseada na "view" e seus
        // elementos, e o seu modelo, a data relativa a posicao que vai ser exibida.

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Acho legal citar também que o `ViewPager` constrói as `Views` sobre demanda, isso é, ele por padrão mantém na memória 3 `Views` (a visível, a anterior e a próxima), conforme você vai navegando ele destrói e constrói as `Views`. Esse comportamento pode ser alterado pelo atributo `OffscreenPageLimit` (sendo 1 por padrão), mas a idéia dele é para dar fluidez ao movimento de `Slide`.

Referências:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: não deu pra te responder com comentário... Comentei com resposta (está acima da sua), não sei se é o certo, mas não achei saída

Comment: Ok, você poderia ter atualizado sua pergunta. Se puder faça que é para não confundir quem venha através da sua pergunta;

Comment: Ok, e excluo a que fiz errado junto com os comentários ?

Comment: @FelipeSantiago Pode ser, mas é só migrar mesmo. Pode até colocar um marcador, e coloque o código mais atualizado até agora.